# How to make collection view cell height equal to the text with the highest height and programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a collection view which scrolls horizontally much like a carousel.

**The height and width of all the cells should be equal to the cell which has the longest text.**

It doesn't do this however and instead expands it's width depending on the length of the text which results into different widths of cells though the height remains constant.

max number of lines for the text is only 4.

[image: Sample gif]

I tried other answers in SO but none of them worked for me.

Here is my code, I am using SnapKit for constraints.

#### View Controller

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    let viewModel: [SeatViewModel] = [.init(text: "single text"), .init(text: "slightly longer text."), .init(text: "very very very very long long text")]
    
    var collectionViewSize: CGFloat = 10
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.register(SeatCardCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SeatCardCell")
        return cv
    }()
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let collectioCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SeatCardCell", for: indexPath) as? SeatCardCell else { fatalError() }
        collectioCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor.green, .red, .black, .brown, .yellow].randomElement()
        collectioCell.viewModel = viewModel[indexPath.row]
        return collectioCell
    }
}
```

#### Cell and View Model

```
struct SeatViewModel {
    let text: String
}

class SeatCardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var viewModel: SeatViewModel? {
        didSet {
            configure()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    let seatImageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
    
    let seatLabel: CustomLabel = {
        let label = CustomLabel()
        return label
    }()

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    
    private func configure() {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        seatLabel.text = viewModel.text
        seatLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        seatLabel.sizeToFit()
        seatImageView.image = .strokedCheckmark
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [seatImageView, seatLabel])
        stackView.spacing = 0
        stackView.alignment = .center
        
        addSubview(stackView)
        
        seatImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.size.equalTo(40)
        }
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - CUSTOM TITLE LABEL
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        self.textColor = .darkGray
        self.textAlignment = .left
        self.numberOfLines = 4
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. I think you should have either the width or the height fixed and vary the other one. If not, the width of the UILabel can (theoretically  of course) go to infinity and numberOfLine = 4 won't do anything, right?

Comment: You have to give the collection view the dimensions of the cell. If the longest cell is not the first cell, what dimensions do you give the first cell? Therefore, you have to know the longest cell in advance and use that computation to give every cell that width.

Comment: @Asteroid

 I thought of that too. Now I am looking how to get the maximum size perhaps calculating the size of the largest label. my labels are inside my cells so challenge now is how to pass that to view controller. Perhaps you have an idea?

Comment: You don’t need to pass it from the cell to the vc. Once you have the width of the label, you have the width of the cell. You can estimate the height of the cell. Then you set the cell size using the delegate method sizeForItemAt.

Comment: @Asteroid oh can you show me an example?

My sizeForItemAt is in ViewController

Comment: @Asteroid Also my UILabel set in the cell class. So not sure how to pass it's size

Comment: You don’t need to set the size of cell or the label inside the cell class. You just set it through the sizeForItemAt, similar to what Sanzio mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Asteroid Yes but my size will depend on the UILabel's height. So I also need to get the height of the UILabel, problem is my UILabel is in cell class.

Is there a way to get the height of the UILabel from cell class?

Comment: Do all cells have the same height? How do you envision it?

Comment: @Asteroid Yes it should be the same height. The height should be equal to the cell with the tallest height of UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all of the cells to be the same size...

One possible solution would be to use `NSString.boundingRect`. In a place where you only need to calculate this once, for example in `viewDidLoad,` determine the bounding rect of the largest text:

```
var maxTextWidth: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // All the other code you currently have, plus:

    let boundingWidth = 9999 // Something arbitrarily large
    let boundingHeight = 34 // Make this the height of however many lines you want
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: boundingWidth, height: boundingHeight)
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)] // Put any other necessary attributes to accurately calculate the size of the text
    
    for vm in viewModel {
        let width = NSString(string: vm.text).boundingRect(with: estimatedSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil).width
        if width > maxTextWidth {
            maxTextWidthWidth = width
        }
    }
}
```

And then you also need to provide this size to the collection view using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = maxTextWidth + // Any padding you want
    let height = // Height of text plus any padding
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

More documentation on `boundingRect` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize)